# form fields ignoring <div> tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing my checkout page.
I want to create custom layout, that's why i'm selecting each checkout form field individually.

Currently im using `woocommerce_form_field();` function to display fields.

I dont know why, but it is ignoring `<div>` tags.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is stupid.
The reason for this was a woocommerce class `woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper` i guess there is some kind of callback to that specific class. When you change it to something custom, then everything works fine.